# How to add dynamically generated fields in forms to the database rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

**Hello everyone I am trying to build one address book where a user can insert his details .

1. A user can insert his information from the form , i am providing dynamic fields if he wants to add more then 1 info like a number can be of type home and personal.
   My Query is how to bind those dynamic values to the rails form and submit the data to the db.**

My model look like a user can have an data which has info type info name and info data
For Example a user can insert a **infotype= Number infoname = Homephone infodata = 23623623** a user can insert as many numbers he wants of different type.Please help
I am doing it like this

```
 <%= form_for @client_info, :validate => true do |f|%>
<% if @client_info.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation", class="alert-message Warning">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@client.errors.count, "error") %> Occured</h2>
    <ul>
        <% @client.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li>
            <%= msg %>
        </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<select id = "opts" >
    <option value = "0">Select Option</option>
    <option value = "1">Phone Number</option>
    <option value = "2">Address</option>
    <option value = "3">Date</option>
    <option value = "4">Email</option>
    <option value = "5">Link</option>
</select>
<form>
    <div id="ap"></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#opts").change(function() {
            if($("#opts").val() == ("1")) {
                $("#ap").append('<div id="phn"><select id ="phn"><option>Personal</option><option >Home</option><option >Custom</option></select> <input type ="text" id="ad"></input>' + '<a href="#" class="remove1" id="rm" >Remove</a></div>');
            }
            if($("#opts").val() == ("2")) {
                $("#ap").append('<div id= "add"><select id ="add"><option>Home Address</option><option >Work Address</option><option >Custom</option></select> <textarea rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>' + '<a href="#" class="remove2" id="rm" >Remove</a></div>');
            }
            if($("#opts").val() == ("3")) {
                $("#ap").append('<div id ="date"><select id ="date"><option>Birthday</option><option >Anniversary</option><option >Custom</option></select> <input type ="text" id="datepic" ></input>' + '<a href="#" class="remove3"  id="rm" >Remove</a></div>');
            }
            if($("#opts").val() == ("4")) {
                $("#ap").append('<div id ="email"><select id ="email"><option>Home Email</option><option >Work Email</option><option >Custom Email</option></select> <input type ="text"></input>' + '<a href="#" class="remove4" id="rm" >Remove</a></div>');
            }
            if($("#opts").val() == ("5")) {
                $("#ap").append('<div id="link"><select id ="link"><option>Profle</option><option >Blog</option><option>Homepage</option><option>Custom</option></select> <input type ="text"></input>' + '<a href="#" class="remove5" id="rm" >Remove</a></div>');
            }

        });
        $('.remove1').live('click', function() {
            $("#phn").remove();
            return false;
        });

    });

</script>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit :class => "btn primary" %> <a href="<%= clients_path %>" class="btn">Cancel</a>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Now i want to add this html generated fields to my rails form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the inputs will be passed as params, you can loop through them and save them pragmatically in your Controller on the create action.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the numbers in a separate model with a one-to-many relationship between them, something like this:

```
class User
  has_many :user_infos
end

class UserInfo
  belongs_to :user

  # attributes:
  # user_id (what user this info belongs to)
  # type (could be Number, Email, whatever)
  # name (an identifier like "home phone", "work email" etc)
  # data (the actual value)
end
```

Then you can just add a controller for the `UserInfo` model where you can add info to a user.

Comment: I did it with that approach now i want to do it with only one model file..thanks for reply..

Comment: Then I guess you use a more fitting database engine, such as a document-based database (e.g. mongodb), or just store a serialized array of the user_infos in a text field in the user model. That second option makes it kind of messy to try to implement a "search by number" function or similar, though.

Comment: Hey Martin can you please take a look to my question again i have added the code and made some changes..

Comment: Yes, now it looks like a completely different question, that only has to do with using javascript to add the actual html to the form. You can just do something synonymous to your remove-function to add stuff to the form.